# Form designer in visual studio overrides my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I made my toolstrip too narrow. I went into the Form1.Designer.cs and tried to fix it. I found:

```
this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 25);
```

and changed 25 to 55. When I run visual studio again it tells me that the code changed, and asks me if I want to run it. But it seems like the graphical design tool somehow overrides my changes, because the with stays the same when I run the application again.

I found this interesting bit of code in the Form1.Designer.cs

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
```

Is there something I can do there to make the graphical design tool not able to change my code?

Yeah I also tried the most obvious solution by trying to change the layout in the graphical tool itself, but I can't re-size the toolstrip there

Comment: Change it after the initialize in the form.cs file or change from the design form

Comment: _but I can't re-size the toolstrip there_ then there probably is some other constraint at work here. You normally can edit the designer.cs (with a little care).

Comment: It will always be overriden, as stated by the comment. You have two choices: Change it in the graphical designer, or force it in the code behind. Since the UI don't seem to work, do it in the code behind.

Comment: Did you try putting your code after the call to `InitializeComponent()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `AutoSize` property to `false`

```
this.toolStrip1.AutoSize = false;
this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 55);
```

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson, if you want also to modify size of toolStripItems, set their AutoSize to `false` too